# Processing methods/threads in correct order

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have an application that is quite complex (it's a command and control center spring + angular based application that is meant to be used by police and other emergency center controllers).

Main component of application (lets call it backbone [spring web app]) is communication with different applications/hardware. Most of that communication is done by using RabbitMQ messages (lets call them telegrams or in short TMs).

When one of that TMs is received by backbone new thread is created and in it some method/methods is/are executed.

The problem is that it can happen that backbone receives two or more TMs almost at the same time, and since they are executed in different threads it can happen that they are not finessed in same order as they arrived and hence wrong information is presented to the user.

Usually, problems like this I handle with Redis. I have a redis lock that basically looks like this

```
distributedRedisLocker.lock(() -> {
    executeSomeMethod();
}, howLongIsLockKept, howLongDoWeWaitForItToFinnish);
```

But in this case I would like to avoid using redis, is there any other java/spring based solution to this?

I do not need it to be same as redis lock that I have, only what I want is that TMs are proccessed in order they arrive, and if one of them fails somewhere in method execution that it does not block the next one forever.

Comment: How about processing these TMs in a single-thread executor like `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`?

Comment: This sounds like the right thing, will try it out and update on progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reposting as an answer.*

One way to solve your problem is to avoid concurrency. You could use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` which only uses one thread:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

and then

```
executor.execute(...);
```

or

```
executor.submit(...);
```

This would help you avoid races: if some TM `A` is added to execution queue defined by this executor before some TM `B`, then `A` will be executed before `B` as a whole.

Also, no explicit locks are involved (apart from implicit ones that can be contained inside the executor implementation, but they are encapsulated and will not stay handing forever in case of an error).

There is a subtle moment: if two TMs arrive at the same time, it's impossible to predict which will be added earlier and which later.

Comment: What I was wondering about is what if I have TMs of different types, and if I get two TMs at the same time but with different types I would like them to be executed immediately and not to wait on the first one to finnis. Would that work ?

Comment: Are TMs of different types independent of each other? If it's ok to execute them concurrently, you could create a single-threaded executer per TM type and execute your TM on executor selected by TM type.

Comment: Yes they are independant. Will try to do it. I was thinking about it, I think this can be done using java synchronized block.

Comment: You don't need a synchronization if you only submit your jobs to **different** executors. If you update some shared state as well, then you might need some synchronization.